# redirecting non-exact location directive overflow to a 404 error

Tags: nginx

In my nginx.conf file, I'm using:

```
location /test {
  default_type 'text/html';
  content_by_lua_file '/usr/local/nginx/html/test.lua';
}
```

Requesting /tesABC displays a 404 error

Requesting /testABC displays my test lua script.

How can I modify my configuration to force an exact match on /test to let /testABC be handled by the 404 error?

Ideally, I need `/test` and `/test/anything` to direct to `/test` as it does currently, while `/testAnything` should be picked up by the 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add = before the path on your location to define an exact match:

```
location = /test {
  default_type 'text/html';
  content_by_lua_file '/usr/local/nginx/html/test.lua';
}
```

Extra details on url matchs for location:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Incoming in 3hrs! You would have had it by now if it weren't for this -- http://i.imgur.com/fTsRIzQ.png Have an upvote while you wait. =]